# GNU Octave the lambda in the output of the sqp function

Tags: lambda, octave, gnu

I am using the `sqp` function in GNU Octave:

```
[x, obj, info, iter, nf, lambda] = sqp(x0, phi, g, h, lb, ub, maxiter, tol)
```

and it seems to be working for me but I would like to know what the outputs `nf` and especially `lambda` mean. On the page for `sqp` it tells you what `x`, `obj` and `info` are but not the other two. Also is it a good thing if your optimization leads to a `lambda` where all the values are zero?

Answer (score 0):

The lambda is a Matlab-style lagrangian optimality structure.  You can find the documentation here:

[Lagrange Multiplier Structures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lagrange-multiplier-structures.html)

If they are all zero, your optimization is failing, or you are using a solver without meaningful lagrangians (maybe by not supplying gradient?)  Check the 'info' output for more details.

'nf' is the width of the last Jacobian computed by the algorithm.   I'm not sure what if any use that has for the user, but there are some comments in the code that indicate someone was using it for debugging at some point...

Comment: Thanks BadZen. I think this info (but fuller) should be included in the GNU Octave sqp page.